# How to enable virtualization in Azure VM

Tags: azure, docker, virtual-machine, docker-machine

I am going through the documentation on Docker Get Started (Part 4), and one of the first steps there is to create a VM using VirtualBox. now I've met all prerequisites and have everything set up, but this step fails on error message

```
Creating CA: /home/tadeasbucha/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem
Creating client certificate: /home/tadeasbucha/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
```

I don't have access to any hardware machine on which I could try this one. Is it possible to set up Azure VM (Ubuntu 16.04) to enable virtualization? I've also tried to disable the virtualization check when creating the VM, but in that case it's stuck on assigning IP address.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to find a solution which is very easy and maybe I just didn't read the VM sizes description thoroughly. Because I had my VM on size Dv2, which unfortunately doesn't offer nested virtualization. When I increased the size of the VM to Dv3 (which apparently has the nested virtualization enabled by default with no further hassling inside of the VM), I was able to create the VMs inside of my VM with no issues.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Tadeáš Bucha's answer, you must choose Dv3, even the newer Dv4's do not work

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on other people's, but wanted people to know this detail since it really tripped me up.

Comment: Thank you for you comment @patatacka, I was on Dv4. I do confirm "D2as_v4" doesn't support virtualization ("Docker"), at least, out-of-the-box, while D2s v3 does.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using a VM size that doesn't support Nested virtualization. I just had to use a size that supports it and, most importantly, set the **Security Type** to **Standard** (in the **Basics** section). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv3-dsv3-series) is a list of D(s)v3 VMs that support **Nested virtualization**.

Answer (score 1):

D and E Knowing that it mattered what kind of VM you choose with respect to having virtualization enabled I created a **Standard D8s v3** VM. But when trying to get Hyper-V setup with this script

```
Install-WindowsFeature Hyper-V, Containers
```

I got the error

```
Install-WindowsFeature : A prerequisite check for the Hyper-V feature failed.
1. Hyper-V cannot be installed because virtualization support is not enabled in the BIOS.
```

Thought it might be working when changing size to **Standard D4s v3**, but to no avail.
Tried creating a new VM **Standard D4s v3**, but the same issue.

So, contrary to various internet resources mentioning that the v3 series VM should have virtualization enabled this clearly is not the case today - any longer?
Would ove to learn what VM series do have vritualization enabled or how I could get it turned on on an Azure VM.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition on a Standard_D4vs_v3. Did you ever figure out a solution to enable virtualization?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work out of the box by creating a VM with the "Standard" security type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1340315/hyper-v-cannot-be-installed-because-virtualization

Answer (score 0):

I think they've made changes recently.

> Virtualization applications other than Hyper-V are [not supported for nested virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization#3rd-party-virtualization-apps). This includes any software that requires hardware virtualization extensions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-template-vm-using-script?tabs=powershell

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35208039)